# Не правильно работает слайдер на JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой код двух слайдеров

```js
   $('.button').click(function(){
        var currentSlide = $('.item.current');
        var currentSlideIndex = $('.item.current').index();
        var nextSliderIndex = currentSlideIndex + 1;
        var nextSlide = $('.item').eq(nextSliderIndex);

        currentSlide.removeClass('current');

        if(nextSliderIndex == ($('.item:last').index()+1)) {
            $('.item').eq(0).addClass('current');
        } else {

            nextSlide.addClass('current');
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .item {
        padding: 10px;
        background: royalblue;
        margin: 10px;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: #fff;
        display: none;
    }
    .item.current {
        display: block;
    }
    .button {
        background: #2d990d;
        width: 140px;
        padding:10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }

</style>



    <div class="slider">
        <div class="button"> next slide 1</div>

        <div class="item current">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>

    </div>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="button"> next slide 2</div>

        <div class="item current">11</div>
        <div class="item">22</div>
        <div class="item">33</div>
        <div class="item">44</div>
        <div class="item">55</div>

    </div>
```

Не могу понять почему показывает слайд 1, 3 и 5. И как сделать чтоб второй слайдер тоже работал ?

Comment: index() не правильный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И не должен был работать. У вас же `$('.item')` собирает все такие элементы на странице, а должен собрать только в рамках текущего блока. Значит, код должен строиться на `$(this).siblings()`. В данном случае, `$(this)` указывает на элемент, который запустил функцию - кликнутая кнопка. А `siblings()` - все его соседние элементы.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  var currSlide = $(this).siblings('.current');
  var items = $(this).siblings('.item');

  var index = items.index(currSlide); // Индекс текущего среди всех item
  currSlide.removeClass('current');
  index = (index == items.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;

  items.eq(index).addClass('current');
})
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background: royalblue;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.item.current {
  display: block;
}

.button {
  background: #2d990d;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="button"> next slide 1</div>

  <div class="item current">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>

</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="button"> next slide 2</div>

  <div class="item current">11</div>
  <div class="item">22</div>
  <div class="item">33</div>
  <div class="item">44</div>
  <div class="item">55</div>

</div>
```

P.s. длинные и детальные названия переменных - не обязательны для трех строчек кода)

Comment: А что лучше использовать, когда допустим нужно найти элемент "первого уровня" (`this > elem`), `.find()` или `.siblings()`? А то обычно `.find()`ом ищу)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 siblings находит только соседние элементы, которые лежат рядом и не вложены в дополнительные теги. А для вложенных "первого уровня" - наверно правильнее через `.children()`, но тоже не заморачиваюсь, и часто через find, как более универсальный... если вдруг в будущем захочется подредактировать HTML - а скрипт уже забыт)

Comment: понял-принял, спасибо)

Comment: Вот так решил. $('.slider').click(function(event){
    if (event.target.className === 'button' ) { 
      
    }

})

Answer (score 0):

- Инкапсулируйте нажатие на кнопу внутри обёртки слайдера `let wrapper = $(this).parent()`.
- Следите за приращением индексов.

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
    let wrapper = $(this).parent(),
      currentSlide = wrapper.find('.item.current'),
      currentSlideIndex = wrapper.find('.item.current').index() - 1,
      nextSliderIndex = currentSlideIndex + 1,
      nextSlide = wrapper.find('.item').eq(nextSliderIndex);
    currentSlide.removeClass('current');
    if(nextSliderIndex == (wrapper.find('.item:last').index())) {
        wrapper.find('.item').eq(0).addClass('current');
    } else {
        nextSlide.addClass('current');
    }
})
```

```css
.item {
        padding: 10px;
        background: royalblue;
        margin: 10px;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: #fff;
        display: none;
    }
.item.current {
        display: block;
    }
.button {
        background: #2d990d;
        width: 140px;
        padding:10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="button"> next slide 1</div>
        <div class="item current">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="button"> next slide 2</div>
        <div class="item current">11</div>
        <div class="item">22</div>
        <div class="item">33</div>
        <div class="item">44</div>
        <div class="item">55</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Понял спасибо !   Решил  делегированием  и увидел где неправильно с индексами сделал.

Comment: Кто минусует рабочие ответы - хотя бы обосновывайте. Детский сад же)